# Use of Switch in MS Access SQL

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2007

I'm trying to do a basic calculation in MS Access SQL.

I have a table called `Weekly`, with weekly stats for each user, includes the following columns: `User`, `Fail`, `Pass`, `Approve` and `Reject` (and some unimportant id and date values).

When I perform the following query:

```
SELECT User, Switch(Approve>0,Pass/Approve, Approve = 0, Null) AS passed_approved_ratio, Switch(Reject>0,Fail/Reject, Reject= 0, Null) AS fail_reject_ratio
FROM Weekly
```

I get an `#ERROR` value in several resulting rows.

I've tried it with and without the second condition+value in the `Switch` funciton (`Switch(Approve>0, Pass/Approve)`,

Fail, Pass, Approve and Reject all have a non-null numerical value in the Weekly table, so why don't they resolve to a Null value when Approve or Reject are 0?

Comment: Can the values be < 0 ? Try Approve <= 0 as the second argument.

Comment: There are no negative values in the table. In any case, a negative value should result in Null because no conditions are met (as per the definition of the Switch function)

Answer (score 3):

In the Office help it states:

> Switch evaluates all of the expressions, even though it returns only one of them. For this reason, you should watch for undesirable side effects. For example, if the evaluation of any expression results in a division by zero error, an error occurs.

Answer (score 2):

The solution:

Use `Iif`, thus:

```
SELECT Iif([Approve]>0, Pass/Approve, Null) as pass_approved_ratio
FROM Weekly
```

That works just fine for now. I'd still like to understand why I was getting errors with `Switch`, though.

Comment: Your attempting to return a string value, but no quotes around it. Try something like: id > 0 , "Pass/Approve". If Pass/Approve is supposed to be a column, I would get rid of the /, and I would also try [Pass/Approve]. Slash and things like space should be avoided in column names and using [] in those cases will help a lot

Comment: Albert, I'm using it as a division operator. The purpose of this expression is to verify that the divisor is non-zero.